# I need custom UI-elements in a terminal. Write my own or use something existing?

Tags: shell

What I need is a program that looks like your standard terminal but that can provide auto-complete suggestions such as in Eclipse and other IDEs, a pop-up window where users can click on the suggestion.

Is it possible to add this feature to any existing terminal or should I write my own terminal with swing or some other graphical library?

Thanks

Comment: what kind of terminal? Unix shell? Windows shell?

Comment: Well, i want it to behave like a unix terminal with the added popup-feature. The users will do very specific things with the terminal so it doesn't matter what other features there are.

However, in this case we've decided to redo the design a bit by doing something similar to SQL UIs where you have a text field and a output field. It therefore doesn't have to be a terminal at all and we'll write it all in swing instead. I'll keep the question open in case someone wonders about this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a shell *environment* by using:

- [bash aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html)
- [bash functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html)
- [bash completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html)

You can also use [gnome zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/) to display dialog boxes directly from your bash functions or aliases.

With an example, which replace the `ls` command by handling errors on a graphical error box:

```
function ls() {
    command ls $@ 2> /tmp/last_error || \
        zenity --error --text="$(cat /tmp/last_error)"
}
```

*NOTE: zenity is only available on gnome desktop*

Comment: Thanks. This is cool and I guess this is as close to the answer I'll get. My problem is that I'm not sure what OS (Unix or Windows) my users will be using so OS independancy is a must. As I mentioned in another comment we'll change the UI a bit and must therefore write everything by ourselves anyway.